# SortedDictionary - cant proceed if node is null

Tags: c#, generics, idictionary

So, my code stop running when a node is null, but i .

```
        Node node = nodeMap[x];  (BREAKS HERE case x isn't in the tree yet)
        if(node == null)
        {
            node = new Node();
            node.Equals(x);
            nodeMap.Add(x, node);
        }
```

> ERROR: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: The key is not in the dictionary.

Comment: what type is nodeMap?

Comment: here the defenition:  public SortedDictionary<string, Node> nodeMap = new SortedDictionary<string, Node>();

Comment: Provided `nodeMap` is a generic `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` you can use the `ContainsKey` method to check if the key is present beforehand. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htszx2dy(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use TryGetValue() method.  If the node exists it'll retrieve it, if not it'll proceed to add the node to the dictionary.  Whichever condition occurs it allows you to use the node object from there on.

```
Node node = null;
if(!nodeMap.TryGetValue(x, out node))
{
    node = new Node();
    node.Equals(x);
    nodeMap.Add(x, node);
}
```

Comment: Isn't there a `!` missing, like `if(!nodeMap.TryGetValue(x, out node))`? Elegant solution with `TryGetValue` in general though.

Answer (score 1):

You are not clear on your question, but I presume you want your error to disapear;).Rather do

```
 Node node;
 if(!nodeMap.ContainsKey(x))
 {
   node = nodeMap[x];
   node = new Node();
   node.Equals(x);
   nodeMap.Add(x, node);
}else
  node = nodeMap[x]
```

*Poof*

Comment: but then node its defined inside of if, and i can't use it outside

Comment: @user3442773 Yes You can only use it in a place where you are sure it exists which is inside the if.

Comment: it doesn't help, because i need to define node after verify and add x, because i will use node later, outside of if

Comment: @user3442773 take a look at my answer. this may be what you're looking for

Comment: @user3442773 See now if this is better

Comment: it works thanks :) but already solve the problem with @CoffeeMuncher answer

Answer (score 0):

Check whether x exists before trying to access it:

```
Node node = nodeMap.Where(y => y.Key == x).FirstOrDefault());
if (node == null)
{
    node = new Node();
    node.Equals(x);
    nodeMap.Add(x, node);
}
```

Hope this is useful ;)

Comment: This will be painfully slow in a big map, because you're potentially interating over the whole map (`O(n)`), whereas an indexer could look an item up quicker (something like `O(log n)`).

Comment: There's really no reason to use a LINQ search as you can call the TryGet method.  The TryGet is extremely optimized, even for large sets.

Answer (score -1):

As stated in documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7w6691xh(v=vs.110).aspx)

> If the specified key is not found, a get operation throws a
>   KeyNotFoundException

So, nothing strange.

Answer (score -1):

Use the `ContainsKey` method to check if it does exist. I presume you're adding it otherwise:

```
if(!nodeMap.ContainsKey(x))
{
    nodeMap.Add(x, new Node());
}

// now you're sure it does exist, as you added it
// above
Node node = nodeMap[x];
```

I removed your invocation of `Equals`. Under no account should `Equals` have side effects, and therefore the call should not be needed unless you work with the return value.